# Can we preserve the storage class when copying an object to a new bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We have two different buckets: short-term, that has lifecycle policies applied, and retain, where we put data that we intend to keep indefinitely. The way we get data into the retain bucket is usually by copying the original object from the short-term bucket using the JSON API.

The short-term bucket after 30 days moves data to nearline, after 60 days to coldline, and after 90 days deletes the data. The storage class for our retain bucket is standard. When we're copying data from short-term bucket to the retain bucket, we'd like to preserve the storage-class of the file that we're duplicating - is it possible for us to specify the storage class on the destination file using the JSON API?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the storage class it is recommended to perform a [rewrite](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite) instead:

> Use the copy method to copy between objects in the same location and storage class

In the rewrite you should set the storage class. The other way should be in the case that you have separated the objects according to the storage class, but as per my understanding, this is not your case.